# dll under windows

Tags: c++, dll, managed

I need to load .dll dynamically from managed c++ code.
The code below does this

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true,
        CharSet = CharSet::Unicode, ExactSpelling = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention::StdCall)]
    static HMODULE LoadLibrary(LPCTSTR lpFileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true,
        CharSet = CharSet::Unicode, ExactSpelling = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention::StdCall)]
    static BOOL FreeLibrary(HMODULE hModule);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true,
        CharSet = CharSet::Unicode, ExactSpelling = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention::StdCall)]
    static FARPROC GetProcAddress(HMODULE hModule, LPCSTR lpProcName);

    typedef int (*CFunction)();

    int _tmain()
    {
        HMODULE pLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("FunctionDLL.dll"));
        if(pLib != 0)
        {
            FARPROC function = GetProcAddress(pLib, "QFunction");
            if (function != 0)
                MessageBox::Show(Convert::ToString(function()));

            FreeLibrary(pLib);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox::Show(L"Error", L"Couldn't load ell");
            Close();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

But function always is null. I think that dll us wrong. Below a code of dll:

.h file

```
#ifdef __FUNCTIONDLL__
#define __FUNCTIONDLL__

#ifdef FUNCTIONDLL_EXPORTS
    #define FUNCTIONDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define FUNCTIONDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

FUNCTIONDLL_API int QFunction();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif // __cplusplus

#endif // __FUNCTIONDLL__
```

.cpp file

```
#include "FunctionDLL.h"

int QFunction()
{
    return 42;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have a .def in your c++ project ? if not just add a .def with

```
LIBRARY   FunctionDLL
EXPORTS
  QFunction   @1
```

Comment: i simply make a misprint with #ifdef, needed #ifndef